# HTMLTestRunner not working in python 3.7.1

Tags: python-3.x

I am new in python automation.I am not able to use HTMLTestRunner in python 3.7.1. I am getting error

> No module StringIO

I tried with multiple solution but none of them working.

If python 3.7.1 doesn't support HTMLTestRrunner then let me know how to downgrade python version in windows 10.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did any of the "multiple solution" trying to check / install the missing module? It's totally useless to say "multiple solution" if you don't tell what they are.